# Assigning values to a css class, when I drag an object CSS/JavaScript/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I had create project with using lists and cards.

Lists are display one by one, and the cards are one under the other (in list).

I use the directive drag and drop. When I drag one card to other list, before I drop her. Is created on the spot where I hold the card.

```
<li class="DnDPlaceHolder"></li>
```

I used in css `word-wrap: break-word;` then height `li` is different in all the cards (width is constant).

I want to create a shadow card (such a place as if done for this card). I mean, there where I hold card is created

```
<li class="DnDPlaceHolder"></li>
```

But with parameters(height, width) this card which I hold.

The question is how to make that when I drag li Card /li automatically assigns parameters for class "DnDPlaceHolder" with using only pure javascript or angular.

Is it possible to do that at all?

**Edit** by writing shadow, i don't mean (css : box-shadow)

Comment: I believe you can access event when you're dragging (on-drag or something) probably there you will have width and height of the element that's being dragged, if you want more help put some code on some fiddle or pen.

Comment: Please, here, https://plnkr.co/edit/uh92bicwR15ggSRzGZB1?p=preview See where the li size is bigger, and when you want to drag it , And you keep another place in the list,is created li element with class dndPlaceHolder, But he gets rigid parameters with ul > li, if There is no class defined in css dndplaceholder

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is just a proposal, hopefully you will find it helpful. I believe this will get you width/height of dragged element, you can play around and try to get other values from event. To finish this off at that point when you have width/height you could add some scope property named isBigCard=true to scope that will turn on class on that placeholder and make it bigger.

```
     <ul    id="first"
      dnd-list="lists"
       dnd-allowed-types="['item']"
       >

       <li   ng-repeat="item in lists" ng-init="ind = $index"
        dnd-type="'item'"
        dnd-draggable="item"
        dnd-moved="lists.splice($index, 1)"
        dnd-effect-allowed="move"
        dnd-selected="models.selected = item"
        ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === item}"
        >  

          {{item.name}}
         <ol id="second"  style="min-height: 30px" dnd-list="item.cards"
           dnd-drop="dropCallback($index, item, lists, ind)"
           dnd-allowed-types="['card']"
            dnd-dragover="dragoverCallback(event,index, external, type)"
          >
            <li style="list-style-type: none;" ng-repeat="card in item.cards"
             dnd-type="'card'"
             dnd-draggable="card"
             dnd-effect-allowed="move"
             dnd-dragstart="dragStart"
             dnd-moved="item.cards.splice($index, 1)"
            >
          {{card.name}}</li>
          </ol> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Dragover callback that will have width and height after you drag it over:

```
$scope.dragoverCallback = function(event,index, external, type){

  let width = event.srcElement.clientWidth;
  let height = event.srcElement.clientHeight;
  console.log(width, height)
  return true;
}
```